# How to use ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelpers "number_with_delimeter" in script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-helpers

I'm writing a script for my rails application and I'm trying to format the numbers with delimeters so they're easier to read. But I have a problem in calling the number_with_delimeter method from ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelpers

I tried

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::base
    extend ActiveView::Helpers::NumberHelper
    def self.run
        puts "#{number_with_delimeter(1234567)}"
    end
end
MyClass.run
```

but it just doesn't work. I always get undefined method errors. I tried it with include instead of extend and some other variations. None of them worked. I don't know how to proceed.

Is there any way to call this method in a script?

**Note: ** I call the script with `rails r script/my_script.rb`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An elegant solution consists in delegation:

```
def self.run
  puts "#{helper.number_with_delimiter(1234567)}"
end

def self.helper
  Helper.instance
end

class Helper
  include Singleton
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
end
```

---

Sidenotes:

- including modules overloads your class
- including the helpers didn't help because you were working at the class level.
- formatting should not be model's job, you should extract this kind of logic within presenters.

Comment: That looks nice. But is there any way to avoid all these classes and methods? First I didn't had a class. I just added it because I thought I need it to access the Helper.

Comment: reread my answer 1) model is the wrong place 2) if you want to keep it in model, don't overload it

Comment: I don't have a model. I'm using it in a script inside the scripts folder. I just took what I've found in the internet without success.

Comment: I see, so just keep this remark in mind: `if you want to keep it in model, don't overload it`, delegation is the best way to go

Comment: Thanks for taking the time but I don't know what do you mean. I'm not experienced enough with all that stuff. I just want to use the number_with_delimeter function once. I think a better approach would be writing my own function to do so.

Comment: I mean you should always keep things separated, int's not a big deal to add 10 lines of code if it cleans everything

Comment: Ahh now I got it.^^ Thanks. :)

Comment: By the way: It's not working. I get the same error as before: undefined method `number_with_delimeter' for #<MyClass::Helper:0x00000005fe6618> (NoMethodError)... I think it's probably easier to write my own method.

Comment: it's number_with_delimiter